# GTK+2 : how to make a configs and store them to apps

Tags: c, gtk

I've made a simple text editor using C and gtk+ lib, and now want to use a configuration system to store user configuration. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You want [GSettings](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html), a GLib API for storing and retrieving application settings.